# mysql ghost table

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.5 on Windows XP. I have one table which was created through mysql workbench. After couple of sync from workbench to mysql database. This table becomes ghost. When I try to create it, system tells me it already exist. When I try to drop it, system tells me it does not exist. I don't know what to do.

I did changed my table name once to just avoid the problem. But after a while it comes back again even with the new table name. I am in the developing stage. So the database structure changes.

Need to shed some light on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the location where your database files are stored by running this query.

show variables like '%datadir%'

Now look in explorer at this directory, you will see a folder per database.
Open the folder for your database

Your table will be in a group of files called tablename.*

```
*.frm = table definition file  
*.MYI = index file  
*.MYD = datafile
```

Maybe the permissions on the files are incorrect, check the permissions on a valid file and make sure your ghost files have the same permissions.

To remove the table from MySQL do:

1. Make a backup of that directory.
2. Next make a backup of the MySQL database using MySQL administrator or alike tool.
3. Make a subdir named "GhostAway"
4. Stop all MySQL clients and maybe the MySQL server as well
5. Move the ghost table files to dir "GhostAway"

Never delete stuff, just move it instead and always make a backup before.

Comment: I checked on server( it is actually hosted on a windows xp VM). The frm file for that table is not there and it does not show up in "show tables" neither. but I just can't create the table. Whenever I try to create it, this is what I get: 
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`xpdb`.`tb_customerlog`' already exists

Comment: I found my problem. Seems the table exist in innodb, but the frm file is missing. I end up had to create a same named table in test db. and copy the frm file to my database. and drop it, recreate it in my own database. problem solved. Thank you for your help to lead me to the right direction.

Comment: @Tong Tong, Good to hear you solved your problem. Creative solution too will keep that in mind.